# How to get radio button to align with label text throughout of font size changes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm facing css issue where with default font size radio button is perfectly aligned to the label text, but as soon as I zoom in or increase the font size, radio button is no longer aligned with text. I would like to style it so radio button is always aligned with text regardless of font size. What adjustment do I need to make on my css to make this happen? https://codepen.io/Judoboy/pen/OJQqPEW?editors=1100

```css
.label-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: start;
}

.label-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.prefix {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.text-spacing {
  padding-inline-start: 8px;
  padding-inline-end: 4px;
}
```

```html
<label class="label-container">
  <input type="radio" />
  <div>
    <div class="label-text text-spacing prefix">Prefix Text</div>
    <div class="label-text text-spacing">This is label</div>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: do you want the following output: https://codepen.io/nisoojadhav/pen/bGLZPMX ?

Comment: With your example, I had to insert font-size css into label-text class and radio button do stay aligned along with font size changes which what I want. But "text" letter needs to be right below "label text" and semantic html wise label tag needs to wrap both input and texts.

Comment: While I'm still using the solution I posted in your previous question, this seems to be achieved here: [https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9z3mwngs/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9z3mwngs/2/); I'm not posting it as an answer (yet, at least) since I imagine you want to stay with your current solution to that previous problem?

Comment: Only issue with this demo is that radio button is not aligned to "Prefix Text" on the right. It's currently placed above the text, but I need it to be centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the **Grid** solution, we make a 2 x 2 grid, the first column for the radio button and empty cell, second for the labels.

##### Grid solution

```css
.label-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    'input prefix-text'
    'empty label-text';
}

input {
  grid-area: input;
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.label-text:first-of-type {
  grid-area: prefix-text;
  align-self: center;
}

.label-text:last-of-type {
  grid-area: label-text;
}

.prefix {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.text-spacing {
  padding-inline-start: 8px;
  padding-inline-end: 4px;
}
```

```html
<label class="label-container">
   <input type="radio" />
   <div class="label-text text-spacing prefix">Prefix Text</div>
   <div class="label-text text-spacing">This is label</div>
</label>
```

##### Flexbox solution

```css
.label-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

input {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
}

.label-text {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 1;
}

.prefix {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.text-spacing {
  padding-inline-start: 8px;
  padding-inline-end: 4px;
}
```

```html
<label class="label-container">
  <input type="radio" />
  <div>
    <div class="label-text text-spacing prefix">Prefix Text</div>
    <div class="label-text text-spacing">This is label</div>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: Almost works, but when I reduce the font-size to 10px then radio button is no longer properly aligned. Only when I increase the size, they are aligned, but not when I reduce the size.

Comment: Yes now it works perfectly! Just wondering, is this achievable using flexbox as well? Or is grid more efficient for this particular css case?

Comment: I've updated the snippet, added the flexbox solution, and made some small changes to the grid.

Comment: For flexbox solution, is there a way to align radio button without using "top: -9px"? Since this is manually controlled, when font is reduced to 10px, it doesn't align like grid solution.

Comment: It's not entirely manually, with flexbox and `align-items: center` we have a center position. Then we move our radio button up, but the radio button still depends on flexbox. I've added small changes to the flexbox solution.